# How do you efficiently support "sub-bitstrings" in a bitset like class in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I want to have my own class like `std::bitset` that extends `std::bitset`'s functionality and I want to overload `operator()(size_t start, size_t end)` such that it returns the bits from `this` from `start` to `end` but shifted so that `end` is now in the lowest bit position.  It should also support moving bits from bitsets with different sizes:

```
        ****  +++
  FEDCBA9876543210 -- position
x=1010101010111000 -- bits
        ****  +++
```

x is a `mybitset<16>` and y is a `mybitset<4>`

what I would like to be able to do is:

```
y = x(2,4); // y is now 0100 see +++ above
x(6,9)=y;   // z is now 101010 0100 111000  see **** above
```

This seems reasonable enough using std::string conversion (`x.to_string().substr()`), but I'd like to keep to just integral manipulations for performance.

EDIT: This needs to work with sizes above 64: e.g. `mybitset<1024>`

Is there a way to do this in C++11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<size_t bits>
std::bitset<bits> subset(std::bitset<bits> set, int min, int max)
{
    const int ignore_hi = bits-max;
    return (set << ignore_hi) >> (ignore_hi + min);
}
```

Tested at: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a17c8431255b62b.  I think it can be optimized slightly, I think a shift can be elided, but I'm too lazy to analyze it, and hopefully the optimizer can figure it out itself.

Usually, if you want a range of bits, the correct answer is to use a bitfield instead of a bitset.  However, since you seem to have a thousand bits, use a class instead.

```
struct flags {
   int height : 3; //3 bits
   int is_square : 1; //1 bit (as if bool)
   int width : 3; //3 bits
}; //keep in mind that a 1 bit int has possible values of `0` and `-1`.
```

If you want the wierdo `bitset` truncation, this is untested.  These operations *could* be done more efficiently as a single operation, but they might also be convenient separate.  I wouldn't bother optimizing unless profiling shows it's necessary.

```
template<class dst_bits, src_bits>
std::bitset<maxbit-minbit> convert_bitset(std::bitset<src_bits> src) {
    std::bitset<maxbit-minbit> result;
    for(int i=0; i<maxbit-minbit; i+=64)
         result |= std::bitset<maxbit-minbit>((src>>i).to_ulllong())<<i;
    return result;
}

template<size_t src_bits, minbit, maxbit>
std::bitset<maxbit-minbit> subset(std::bitset<src_bits> set)
{
    const int ignore_hi = src_bits-maxbit;
    std::bitset<src_bits> range = (set << ignore_hi) >> (ignore_hi + min);
    return convert_bitset<maxbit-minbit>(set);
}
```

If you want truncation with runtime sized min/max, it  seems like you should re-evaluate the design. Not that it's wrong, but it should be confirmed to be right before proceeding.  If you still insist on proceeding, here's a proxy that should be able to convert from one size to another implicitly, merely alter the first `subset` function to return `proxy_bitset<bits>` instead of `std::bitset<bits>`.

```
template<size_t src_bits>
struct proxy_bitset {
    proxy_bitset(std::bitset<src_bits> src) :src(src) {}
    template<size_t dst_bits>
    operator std::bitset<dst_bits>() const {return convert_bitset<dst_bits>(src);}
private:
    std::bitset<src_bits> src;
};
```

Comment: editted question to reflect this needs to work with large sizes, but +1 since you got this in before the edit

Comment: you can't do `subset(x, 6, 9)=y` you would need to overload it to create a new object which when assinged to, assigned to the range of x, and when assigned from, assigned from the range

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum yep, but it is not *impossible* - you may need to create some other class that handles this, so that the operator() returns proxy<bits_in_x>, but then operator= for the proxy class needs to be templated.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: since the destination size has to have a fixed number of bits, you must know the bit indexes at compile time.  I've reworked the functions to take advantage of this, and viola, it all (should) work.

Comment: @user3125280: Since the bits in teh destination is known at compile time, I'm going to assume the min/max are also known at compile time.  Done under those assumptions.

Comment: getting closer - as mentioned the general way is with proxies, but its, tricky

Comment: @MooingDuck i don't have time to read it now sorry, but that's a fair assumption (although really only the size of x and y needs to be known, it would be weird if the others were runtime) ..i already upvoted a while ago.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: Are you doing subsets with runtime ranges into a compiletime sized bitset result?  In that case, yes you'd want a proxy, but it also seems like you should re-evaluate the design. (Not that it's wrong, but it should be confirmed to be right before proceeding)

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: Added a proxy.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: It may amuse you to know that two days ago I needed code that took a sub-bitstring of a bitset with variable left/right.

Comment: I don't follow the reason for building `range` in order to `&` with `set`. Why not just `return (set << ignore_hi) >> (ignore_hi + min)`?

Comment: " I think it can be optimized slightly, I think a shift can be elided, but I'm too lazy to analyze it, and hopefully the optimizer can figure it out itself."
Thanks for figuring out the optimization. I'll update it